# Maximum number of static leases I can define in isc-dhcp server

Tags: centos, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I am trying to figure out the max number of leases I can define in `dhcpd.leases` file for the DHCP server. Does anyone know how many max can it support?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit beyond the scope of the pools. You can configure an IP reservation for each individual IP address in each of your DHCP pools.